# what is the first mention of 2063 as year of First Contact?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-first-contact

In any medium whatsoever - novels, interviews, television episodes, movies, etc - what is the earliest mention of 2063 as year of First Contact?

Comment: You mean before the movie was written?  Are you trying to ask if that date had been specified before the movie or if it originated with the movie?

Comment: @DavidW yes exactly.

Comment: @Maximus1987 you mean everything, right?

Comment: @Rainbow I will accept simply the first mention ever ie doesn't have to be the first mention in each medium.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't speak for all the novels, because there may have well been something out there somewhere (although I doubt it), but in terms of the films and TV, that date originated in *Star Trek: First Contact*. I have a first edition of *[The Star Trek Chronology](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Chronology)* printed in 1993 (which I just checked), and there's no definite, official, date of first contact between (Earth) humans and anyone else that is given, and in fact nothing is listed for 2063 at all. Cochrane's first warp flight was estimated to have been in 2061, based on extrapolation from the TOS episode "[Metamorphosis](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Metamorphosis_(episode))", and the date of around 2065 for the SS *Valiant* having reached the Galactic Barrier which occurred 200 years before the episode "[Where No Man Has Gone Before](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Where_No_Man_Has_Gone_Before_(episode))", later established to have been set in 2265.

The 2065 date for *Valiant* being lost was confirmed by a screen display on the *Star Trek Enterprise* episode "[In a Mirror Darkly](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/In_a_Mirror,_Darkly,_Part_II_(episode))".

Later editions of the Chronology were updated due to the date given in the film.